# Error while trying to load recyclerview in custom FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-custom-view

I am trying to create a custom FrameLayout which has a recycler view inside it. But I am getting an error while inflating it.

```
class ListingLayout(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet?, intDefStyle: Int)
    : FrameLayout(context, attributeSet, intDefStyle)
{

    constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet?) : this(context, attributeSet, 0)
    constructor(context: Context) : this(context, null)

    var ListAdapter: ListAdapter
    

    init
    {
        layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        )
         = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.templates_listing_layout, this, true)

        ListAdapter = ListAdapter(ArrayList(), this)

        try {
            val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.list)
            val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
            recyclerView.adapter = ListAdapter
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    }

}
```

The XML  File - templates_listing_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/template_list" />
    
</FrameLayout>
```

The output for the stack-trace is :

**2022-07-21 23:40:06.143 8279-8279/com.dash.debug W/System.err: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.dash.component.TemplateListingLayout cannot be cast to androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView**

2022-07-21 23:40:06.143 8279-8279/com.dash.debug W/System.err:     at com.dash.component.TemplateListingLayout.(TemplateListingLayout.kt:41)**

2022-07-21 23:40:06.143 8279-8279/com.dash.debug W/System.err:     at com.dash.component.TemplateListingLayout.(TemplateListingLayout.kt:24)**

And this is val recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.list) line number 41.

Comment: can you please share the code for templates_listing_layout?

Comment: I am not sure but maybe doing the next approach could fix the problem.  Your class ListingLayout extends from FrameLayout so you dont need a FrameLayout in your xml (if you want it, then you can use the merge tag).  You can remove the xml and do in your class in the init: addView(recyclerView) and thats all.  In my opinion i prefer the xml but using the RecyclerView as only viewgroup parent, adding here the linearLayout and the list and size to see the preview